# jQuery issue passing href at ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am in some unusual kind of situation.

Look at the code below

HTML:

```
<a href="?productid=13&amp;refer=1&amp;opr=view" title="Click to view details or Mark as 'Featured Product'" id="product_13">Demo Product</a>
```

and my jQuery code looks like

```
jQuery('a[id^="product_"]').bind("click", function(){
    ... calling ajax ... with following parameters ...
    this.href
});
```

and on server-side, using PHP, I get all those parameters differently

```
$_GET['productid']=13
$_GET['refer']=1
$_GET['opr']=view
```

but I need to get as single string (**?productid=13&refer=1&opr=view**), any help guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get $_GET contents as single string, you can use

```
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Isn't it easier to just add specific class to your link, like "product_link", so you can

```
jQuery('a.product_link').bind("click", function(){ /* your code here */ });
```

This way you are relying only on your abstract class name and not on URL.